# Problem with effective function and arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm trying to write an effective function that receives an array the size of `n` and `a` and `b`.

The function should search all the numbers in the array such that `b-a < array[i]` and collect them to a new sorted array called `incoming`.

For instance, for the input `11,12,8,15,3,12,3,12` , `b=15`, `a=8` the output would be a `6` size array that will contain the values `8,11,12,12,12,15` (anything that is higher than *(b)15-(a)8* ).

This is my own code attempt:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int* f5(int arr[], int n, int a, int b, int* p)
{
    int i,min,minIndex;
    int* incoming = (int*)malloc(*p*sizeof(int));
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>(b - a))
        {
            incoming[i] = arr[i];
            (*p)++;
        }
    }

    return *incoming;

}
void main()
{
    int arr[] = { 12,3,12,3,15,8,12,11 };
    int  p, i;
    int incoming[] = f5(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), 8,15, &p);
    printf("The size is: %d and the new marahc is: ", p);
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        printf("%d", incoming[i]);
    }
    free(incoming);
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by *effective function*, or, why would anyone ever write an ineffective function?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry, my question is if anyone can point out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Anyway, you want : `int incoming[] = f5(...` -> `int *incoming = f5(...` and `return *incoming;` -> `return incoming;`.

Comment: @Caleb English isn't my first language, I'm doing some self-improvement excercises in order to get better at code, and in my language the question is translated that way, maybe I can give you more details

Comment: Where is `p` set, which is controlling memory allocation? In C local variables are not initialised for you.

Comment: @erezzinger _You_ need to tell us first what problem you encountered (such as "when I compile it I get errors", "when I run it gave unexpected results" etc.). Read this: [ask]

Comment: @erezzinger if your english skills are poor you can use translate.google.com, it works very well, even for chinese.

Comment: @Jabberwocky oh that's how I have done previously, but the problem is that the output my array gives isn't sorted (but also doesn't run..) Also I would love you explain why you changed it like that if you have the time, much appreciated (Y)

Comment: Please follow up the compiler warnings given.

Comment: @erezzinger the first modification is needed so the program compiles, `int incoming[] = f5` is simply wrong. The second modification is because `f5` returns a pointer to `int` and `incoming` _is_  already a pointer to `int`. BTW with `return *incoming` you should get a compiler warning (which is actually more of an error)

Comment: @WeatherVane I wanna define a new array that is sorted but I don't know how much memory to assign. p is a pointer to the size of the new array I need to return the size of the new array

Comment: The address of `int p` is passed to the function, which uses `*p` to determine the memory allocation. The `p` has *not been set to any value*.

Comment: @WeatherVane as I was saying, I do not know what to set value on p based on the new array

Comment: Also the compiler says *warning C4047: 'return': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'*.

Comment: @WeatherVane I always wondered why `'return': 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` is only a warning. I'm not aware of any situation where this is not an error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes, but aren't there some kernel usages which return an `int` as a pointer value?

Comment: @WeatherVane so simply assiging a value to p should remove said error?

Comment: There are others errors too, see what the compiler says

Comment: @WeatherVane maybe, I don't know. But this would only work for a 32 bit kernel

Answer (score 0):

So I corrected your `f5` function because you were not allocating your new array properly, since you were doing the malloc with `(*p)` before it was set to the number of elements you needed to store. After that, I ordered the `incoming` array in ascending order as shown in the example output with `qsort`. I also added the part where you take input values from the user, since in the code you've posted you were probably just trying that specific test case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

// compare function for qsort
int mycompare (const void* a, const void* b) {
    int val1 = *(const int*)a;
    int val2 = *(const int*)b;
    
    return (val1 - val2);
}
int* f5(int arr[], int n, int a, int b, int* p) {
    int target = b - a;
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) { // storing number of values > (a-b)
        if (arr[i]>target) (*p)+=1;
    }
    
    int* incoming;
    if ((incoming= malloc((*p)*sizeof(int)))==NULL); // should always check malloc errors
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (i<n && j<(*p)) { // storing values in new array
        if (arr[i]>target) {
            incoming[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    return incoming;
}

void main() {
    int n, a, b, i;
    
    printf("Insert 'a' value: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Insert 'b' value: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Insert array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int arr[n];
    printf("Insert array values: \n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    int size = 0;
    int *incoming = f5(arr, n, a, b, &size);
    qsort(incoming, size, sizeof(int), mycompare); // sorting array
    
    printf("The size is: %d and the new marahc is: ", size);
    for (i=0; i<size;i++) {
        printf("%d ", incoming[i]);
    }
    free(incoming);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `f5` you need to determine the required length to allocate. You could either do an initial pass of the `arr[]` contents to determine the required length, or just set the length to the upper bound `n` and resize it once the actual length is known.

First approach using an initial pass:

```
int* f5(int arr[], int n, int a, int b, int* p)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int* incoming;
    j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>(b - a))
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    incoming = malloc(j*sizeof(int));
    if (incoming == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>(b - a))
        {
            incoming[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    *p = j;
    return incoming;
}
```

Second approach using upper bound for allocated size:

```
int* f5(int arr[], int n, int a, int b, int* p)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int* incoming = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (incoming == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    j = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>(b - a))
        {
            incoming[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    int* resized_incoming = realloc(incoming, j*sizeof(int));
    if (resized_incoming != NULL)
    {
        incoming = resized_incoming;
    }

    *p = j;
    return incoming;
}
```

The above have been written to return `NULL` if `malloc` returns `NULL`.

A third approach would be to start with a small amount for `incoming` and reallocate to a larger amount when necessary.

In `main`, the variable `incoming` needs to be changed from an array type to a pointer:

```
    int* incoming = f5(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), 8,15, &p);
```

Since `f5` can now return `NULL`, the return value should be checked and appropriate action taken:

```
    if (incoming == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

You also need to add code to sort the filtered numbers.

Comment: first of all thank you very much! second of all I wanted to ask you in the first code why did you initialize 'j' twice as 0, also if I do some more loops in the function f5 to sort the incoming will the runtime of the function still stay the size of n? also how would you sort the new array in the most efficient way? and one more thing why in the function f5 you defined incoming as pointer at the beginning? thanks again your code has helped me understand a lot.

Comment: After resetting `j` to 0, we know that it will end up with the same value after the both the first and second loops, since the conditional tests for incrementing `j` is the same in both loops. However, you could replace `j` in the second loop with another variable `k` initialized to 0, and it should end up with the same value as `j`. The sorting needs to be done after the filtering. The number of elements to be sorted is `j` (or `k`, or `*p`). An efficient way to sort the elements is to use the `qsort` library function, as shown in @Mateo Pinna's answer.